# Doing Operations on C# Async Method Result

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am working on converting some synchronous code to async in C# (.NET 4.5). I have a senario where I need to do an operation using the number of models retrieved by a remote query as an input.

An example of the desired behavior:

```
public async Task<List<Model>> GetEntityModelsAsync()
{
    return // some models from a database async
}

public async Task<int> DoSomeWorkWithModelCount() 
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Model>> models = GetEntityModelsAsync();

    // some other code to execute before awaiting

    int count = await models.Count();

    // do more work and return result
}
```

The above code will not compile with the error 'Task<IEnumerable>' does not contain a definition for 'Count'...

I assume this is because the type of the variable is 'Task<IEnumerable>'. Is there any way to extract the result from the task and do operations that are allowed on its type?

I have tried getting the result in this way:

```
int count = await models.Result.Count(); // error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'

await recentApplications.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
```

Am I forced to first await the result into another variable like this:

```
IEnumerable<Model> modelsResult = await models;
int count = modelsResult.Count();
```

Or is there a more streamlined way to do type operations on the results of awaited tasks?

Comment: why don't you await your call to `GetEntityModelsAsync` or use `Task.WhenAll`? you can also use parens to get the order of operations right

Comment: The last option is the correct one. The task return an IEnumerable<Model>, then you can  Count() on that. If you only care about the count, change the async method to return a Task<int> instead, and do the count there.

Comment: You don't have to necessarily create a separate variable. You could do `(await models).Count()` or even `(await GetEntityModelsAsync()).Count()`. Just depends on if you need to work with them in some ways besides just grabbing the count. The key part is to unwrap the task before getting the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you do if you want it in one line:

```
int count = (await models).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
int count = await models.CountAsync();
```